# Override OnClick for menu option when selecting text in a webview

Tags: android

When selecting text in an android webview, you get an action bar allowing you to select all, copy, share, do a web search etc. Is there any way to override the OnClick methods for these options everywhere in my app?

Comment: Do you want to perform a different action? or just get the copied string?

Comment: I want to change the intent for the web search option. I have a browser in the app and I'd like the web search option to immediately launch in the app's browser instead of popping up a dialog asking the user what browser they'd like to choose.